# How to fill the screen with only one element?

Tags: android, layout, size, fixed, fill

I want to make an activity with 2 elements in the screen, one in the bottom, with a fixed size, and one on top of this which one must fill the screen.

[image: Desired layout]

How I can do that in a Layout?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="test" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

use `layout_weight="1"` for 1st element and put `layout_height="0dp"` and use linearlayout as the parent which contains the 2 elements.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do this,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_above="@+id/ll1"
 >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the first element:

```
  android:layout_weight="0.8"
```

and for the second one

```
android:layout_weight="0.2"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Relative Layout like...following example

```
<//you are second element
    android:id="@+id/ui_radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
<///you are second element>

<//you are First element
    android:id="@+id/ui_pager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/ui_radiogroup"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" />
```

Other OPtion use Linear Layout assign android:layout_weight to each element depending upon your requirement

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/footertext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Footer" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/centertext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/footertext"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="center" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete trick :

- Use a `RelativeLayout` to wrap your two items,
- Put `layout_alignParentBottom="true"` on your bottom item
- And `layout_above="@+id/your_bottom_item_id"` on your top item

Here is a complete working example that you can cpy/paste :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/top_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_layout">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/bottom_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use layout_weight="1" for first element and layout height should be match_parent.